# stack up angular-ui-router ui-view with CSS3 z-index

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-router

I would like to stack up 2 ui-views using CSS3 z-index property and angular-ui-router. I drew my inspiration from this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-stateful-modals-angularjs-angular-ui-router/) and here is my implementation:

**index.html**

```
<!-- this is the main ui-view -->
<div id="scene" ui-view="general" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

**index.css**

```
#scene{
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 480px; 
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px white solid;
}
```

Since ui-view are stacked in the order in which they are added (and it is not the disposition that I want), I defined two others html files and their corresponding css as listed below :

**level0.html**

```
<!-- this is the container of the first z-index level -->
<div>
      <ui-view name="z0" class="z0Holder" autoscroll="false"></ui-view>
</div>
```

**level0.css**

```
.z0Holder { 
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 480px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0!important;
}
```

**level1.html**

```
<!-- this is the container of the second z-index level -->
<div>
   <ui-view name="z5" class="z5Holder" autoscroll="false"></ui-view>
</div>
```

**level1.css**

```
.z5Holder { 
        background: transparent;
        position: relative;
        width: 800px;
        height : 55px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 5!important;
    }
```

I load routes from a json file at the starting of the app ( it works fine). This json file looks like this:

```
[
    {
          "name": "zLevel",
          "url": "/zLevel",
          "abstract": true,
          "views": [{
                "name": "general@",
                "templateUrl": "level0.html",
                "controller": "",
                "css": "level0.css"
            },{
                "name": "general@",
                "templateUrl": "level1.html",
                "controller": "",
                "css": "level1.css"         
            }]
    },{
          "name": "confirm",
          "url": "/confirm",
          "parent": "zLevel",
          "views": [{
                "name": "z0@zLevel",
                "templateUrl": "partials/confirmation.html",
                "controller": "confirmationController",
                "css": "stylesheets/confirmation.min.css"
            }]
    },{
          "name": "progressStatus",
          "url": "/progressStatus",
          "parent": "zLevel",
          "views": [{
                "name": "z5@zLevel",
                "templateUrl": "partials/progressStatus.html",
                "controller": "progressStatusController",
                "css": "stylesheets/progressStatus.min.css"     
          }]
    }
]
```

Now I have two problems :

- I only have the level 0 template displayed (the confirmation view)
- I cannot get the two states (progressStatus and confirm) activated at the same time, even if I try with sticky states (ui-router extras)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution, I would be grateful for any assistance.